# How to securely connect to Bitstamp Websocket v2.0 API with python websockets? Certrificate verification error

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, certificate, verify

I'm trying to get real time bitcoin price data from the Bitstamp Websocket v2.0 API. Where can I get the certificate if needed? If download of the certificate is automatic, how can I make sure that it is possible for python to verify the received certificate?

The documentation on the Bitstamp website is rather scarce on this matter. Here's a quote from Bitstamp api documentation:

"Once you open a connection via websocket handshake (using HTTP upgrade header), you can subscribe to desired channels."

Bitstamp api docs: https://www.bitstamp.net/websocket/v2/

Tried searching in websockets documentation: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I have looked into websockets and ssl. Now I know a bit about the handshake but still after much trying and searching I can't figure out what to do.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def bitstamp_ticker():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'wss://ws.bitstamp.net', ssl=True) as websocket:
        pass

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(bitstamp_ticker())
```

From what I understand in the websocket documentation adding ssl=True should be enough to establish a secure connection. But it seems that maybe the bitstamp certificate is not recognized by a Certificate Authority built into Python 3.6. and this is why the error occurs?

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't spend time looking into this ssl cert issue for Bitstamp. But I just disabled ssl cert verification to make the web-socket market data push work.  Below is the sample code, and appreciated if you could share your future progress on this issue.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import websocket
import json
import ssl

bitstamp_endpoint = 'wss://ws.bitstamp.net'


def subscribe_marketdata(ws):
    params = {
        'event': 'bts:subscribe',
        'data': {
            'channel': 'order_book_btcusd'
        }
    }
    market_depth_subscription = json.dumps(params)

    ws.send(market_depth_subscription)


def on_open(ws):
    print('web-socket connected.')
    subscribe_marketdata(ws)


def on_message(ws, data):
    data = json.loads(data)
    print(data)


def on_error(ws, msg):
    print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    marketdata_ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(bitstamp_endpoint, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error)
    marketdata_ws.run_forever(sslopt={'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I will post if I find any improvement on your solution.
First thing I plan to do is to try running the script in Linux... maybe it's a windows specific issue. I've also contacted Bitstamp support and they say it's an isolated case. However I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: how can this data be parsed, eg. when I just want to print(data['bids']) ?